# Regex match last character before set of character from upper sentence

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get the last character from a pattern like this below, the regex need to contain the set present in the name "C16P_P5_VC836" and match the last character from the first id, in this case "4" but this wont be always be a digit, it can be a letter as well.

I did try with something like this `"id([\s\S]*?)C16P_P5_VC836"` but this wont work since I need the info from the ID field just above the name one.

Can someone point me in the right direction, thanks!

```
  "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001",
  "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000F",
  "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000004",
  "name": "C16P_P5_VC836",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could optionally repeat all preceding parts with `"id":` and then capture the last char a-z or digit before the closing double quote in the last line that starts with `"id":` right before the line that has `"name": "C16P_P5_VC836",`

```
(?:"id":\s*"[^"]*",)*\r?\n\s*"id":\s*"[^"]*([a-zA-Z0-9])",\r?\n\s*"name":\s*"C16P_P5_VC836",
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:"id":\s*"[^"]*",)*` Optionally repeat the line with `"id":`
- `\r?\n\s*"id":\s*"[^"]*` Match the last line with `"id":`
- `([a-zA-Z0-9])` Capture a single char a-z or digit in group 1
- `",` Match literally
- `\r?\n\s*` Match a newline and optional whitespace chars
- `"name":\s*"C16P_P5_VC836",` Match the line with C16P_P5_VC836

See a [regex 101  demo](https://regex101.com/r/5HHgIZ/1).